# How can I lookup and return labels from a table in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, lookup

[image]

I would like to return the labels in column F to column C, using column B and E, even though column E has multiple req IDs in some cells? I know I can't use a V Lookup in this case. However is there another formula or lookup function that I could use, to return the labels?

Comment: If you make each of those Req ID numbers a single entry then index() and match(0 will sort it easily.

Comment: @SolarMike Okay thanks, but do I have to manually make each of the req ids in column E a single entry or is there a formula to do that?

Comment: So make use of text to column and separate them - you have a separator.

Comment: You also have the same `REQ ID` listed for different labels.  Is that a mistake in your data?  Or do you want to return both labels?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ahh, thanks. That is a mistake in the data

Answer (score 1):

*Append a comma to both the `find_text` and `search_text` arguments to deal with the comma separated data in column E*

```
B2: =INDEX($F$2:$F$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT(A2,"0\,"), $E$2:$E$7 & ",")),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Great formula. You are king! :-) I tried for hours to solve that!

Answer (score 0):

So, try:

```
IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$7,0)),"Check")
```

[image]

Used iferror() to put "check" as a reminder to make sure "new" numbers are added to the list...