# Ms Excel : vlookup or index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]How to fetch data from table like these? Here the column "Subjects" has been created by extracting respective text from "Subject" column

Comment: Both vlookup() or index() with match() will work. What have you treied? There are examples of vlookup and index with match on here. vlookup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73501173/4961700 and index with match: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73501075/4961700

Comment: Hey Mike, actually this is not a standard table to fetch data from, it has multiple headers so i am getting error. Can you provide an example using this problem?

Comment: Please show us the formula you are using

Comment: Use the column argument in index() to drive which dataset to use. Done this before - search on here.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomadI have edited the picture, you can see the formula i used. For "B" , i dont know why it is fetching me 72 three times!

Comment: @Shishir don't forget to add the last argument of the VLOOKUP formula to be 0 or FALSE to get an exact match, so `=VLOOKUP(AT,N$5:P$9,3,0)`

Comment: @P.b thanks that worked, can you help me with writing a single dynamic formula for the whole table? currently i am selecting tables one by one for A, B etc

Comment: Judging by the picture `=INDEX($J$5:$X$9,ROW(1:1),MATCH(B$4,$J$3:$X$3,0)+2)` where `ROW` creates a counter for the row number of the indexes range and `MATCH` looks for the column matching the letter and offsets (adds) 2.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is one that I posted before:

[image]

You can take it apart and see what each bit does.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have edited the image to include the formula I am using. If you see for "B" I am getting 72 thrice! Can you tell me where I am wrong?